# Run script when interface change it's status

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, networking, routing, libreswan

I need static route when interface is up and delete this route when it goes down, but I have no interface config file to describe shell-command in it.

I have IPSec tunnel created with LibreSwan and tunnel interface vti0 that created by ipsec daemon. Here is the config:

```
conn dc
    authby=secret
    auto=start
    type=tunnel
    esp={{ ipsec_ike_alg }}
    ike={{ ipsec_ike_alg }}
    ikelifetime={{ ipsec_ikelifetime }}
    keylife={{ ipsec_key_lifetime }}
    ikev2=insist
    rekey=no
    fragmentation=yes
    narrowing=yes

    left={{ ipsec_local_ip }}
    leftsubnet={{ ipsec_local_net }}
    right={{ ipsec_remote_ip }}
    rightsubnet={{ ipsec_remote_net }}

    mark=5/0xffffffff
    vti-interface=vti0
    vti-routing=no
    leftvti={{ ipsec_vti_local_ip }}
```

I need to route traffic to subnets behind this ipsec through vti0 tunnel. I can do it manually and everything will work as planned:

```
ip route add {{ ipsec_static_route }} dev vti0 src {{ ipsec_source_ip }}
```

But I want this route appears automatically when vti0 becomes up and disappear when interface down. I tried to do it put my scripts in /etc/network/if-up.d/ and /etc/network/if-down.d/, but it doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$IFACE" = {{ ipsec_vti_interface }} ]; then
    route add -net {{ ipsec_static_route }} dev {{ ipsec_vti_interface }}
fi
```

Maybe there is some native way to create route only for certain networks by LibreSwan? Or I made some mistakes in my scrips?

Comment: Ideally the routes should be dealt with by the VPN server

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to push routes via IPSec without any dynamic routing protocols, such as BGP. And in this case I can't use dynamic routing for the single route.

Comment: BGP is not for dealing routes in VPN servers.

Comment: Yes, I know a little bit about BGP, I mean that I can get connectivity between my Linux server and Cisco ASA/Juniper SRX/etc via IPSec and get routes from dynamic routing over this tunnel, but I don't need it only for single route. I just want static route up when tunnel interface is up